# android server:sending data when button is clickked

Tags: android

i have a android socket server,which just sends "hello" to clients at the startup. i need to send "hello" each time when a button is clicked. i added the code for button,inside the while loop, the app crashed.pls help
(i dont want to display the incoming data)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView1;
    final Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    static String SERVER_IP;
    static final int SERVER_PORT = 5000;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    ServerSocket serverSocket;




    //---get the local IPv4 address---
    public String getLocalIpv4Address() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceEnum = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); networkInterfaceEnum
                    .hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaceEnum
                        .nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> ipAddressEnum = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses(); ipAddressEnum.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress) ipAddressEnum
                            .nextElement();
                    // ---check that it is not a loopback address and
                    // it is IPv4---
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()
                            && InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress
                                    .getHostAddress())) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("IPAddress", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //---make the TextView scrollable---
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }



    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

            try {
                if (SERVER_IP != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                                    + "Server listening on IP: " + SERVER_IP
                                    + "\n");
                        }
                    });

                    //---create an instance of the server socket---
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

                    while (true) {
                        //---wait for incoming clients---
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                        //---the above code is a blocking call;
                        // i.e. it will block until a client connects---

                        //---client has connected---
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                                        + "Connected to client." + "\n");
                            }
                        });





                        try {
                            //---get an InputStream object to read from the
                            // socket---
                            //DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                            //String line=dataInputStream.toString();
                            //textView1.setText(line);

                            final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                            dataOutputStream.writeChars("hello");






                            /*BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                            client.getInputStream()));

                            OutputStream outputStream = 
                                    client.getOutputStream();


                            //---read all incoming data terminated with a \n
                            // char---
                            //String line = null;
                            //while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                //final String strReceived = line;

                                //---send whatever you received back to the
                                // client---
                                //String s = line + "\n";
                                //DataOutputStream saj=new DataOutputStream();

                                //outputStream.write(s.getBytes());

                                /*handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                                                + strReceived + "\n");
                                    }
                                });*/
                                //br.close();
                            //}


                            //---client has disconnected from the server---
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                                            + "Client disconnected." + "\n");
                                }
                            });

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                                            + error);
                                }
                            });                         
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView1.setText(textView1.getText()
                                    + "No internet connection on device."
                                    + "\n");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                final String error = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView1.setText(textView1.getText() + error + "\n");
                    }
                });
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView1.setText(textView1.getText() + "\n" + "Server exited"
                            + "\n");
                }
            });
        }
    }





    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //---get the IP address of itself---
        SERVER_IP = getLocalIpv4Address();

        //---start the server---
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        serverThread.start();

    }




    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {           
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: please add the LogCat

Comment: -1 for no stacktrace included nor available given the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as you "introduced" textview you should do the same with button since now you are trying to find it by id but before you set up a layout. so do this:

```
TextView textView1;
Button button1;
```

and later after

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //---make the TextView scrollable---
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

do

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Also its really hard to help without at least logcat

Comment: is there any problem in writing the button onclick event inside the try in the while loop? it shows a crash

Comment: normally, its no problem if you do it correctly. What crash is it, what does the logcat says?

Comment: If you look through the stack trace, you will see a "Caused by..." line (sometimes more than one). The last one of those is the important one. You would find yyour mistake there or copy logcat so we can see where the problem is

Comment: thank you for your helping. here is the line 06-03 09:01:08.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2492): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: no problem, Null Pointer Exception means that something is null ( non existing for example ) I'm pretty sure that your button is problem so please do "findViewById" part after the setContentView(R.id.layout); since you cant find view on layout before you made that layout a content view